# How to schedule a job on behalf of a service account from another namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes service running in namespace `NA` that is configured to run as a service account `A`.  The service schedules a Kubernetes job in namespace `NB`.  How do I make a job in `NB` act on behalf of service account `A`?  I tried to specify the name of the service account for the job, but I get the following error:

```
Error creating: pods "pod_id_x is forbidden: error looking up service account NB/A: serviceaccount "A" not found
```

P.S. I am using Google Kubernetes Engine

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this can be done by granting Service Account [A] a rolebinding in namespace NB  allowing it to deploy pods. You just need the proper role.

You can simply reference a ServiceAccount from another namespace in the RoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
  namespace: ns2
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-reader-from-ns1
  namespace: ns2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ns1-service-account
  namespace: ns1
```